# Ошибка: return type is incomplete type

Tags: c

Есть некий хедер со следующим кодом (и полное объявление в .c файле):

```
typedef struct TLSchema TLSchema;
```

Он подключается в другом .с файле, где я объявляю функцию:

```
TLSchema parse_schema(char * definition)
{
    TLSchema schema = (TLSchema*)malloc(1000); // просто мокап
    return schema;
}
```

На **первой же** строчке ошибка: return type is incomplete type. ЧЯДНТ?

Я по-прежнему балуюсь и не все до конца понимаю, поэтому ответы для начинающих только приветствуются. Пишется-билдится все из Codeblocks.

Comment: А определение структуры где?

Comment: В соседнем файле .c

    typedef struct TLSchema {
        size_t length;
        TLToken entries[];
    } TLSchema;

Comment: Вы создаете экземпляр структуры вот тут "TLSchema schema". В этом месте компилятору нужно определение структуры, чтобы понять, сколько памяти выделять на стеке. А в вашем случае ему доступно только объявление.

Comment: @dzhioev, я в хедере должен ее полностью объявлять?

Comment: @Fike, Вы пытаетесь присвоить структуре 

     struct TLSchema schema; 

**адрес** (наверное, звездочку пропустили). Естественно, ругается.

Правильно

     TLSchema *schema = (TLSchema*)malloc(1000);

или можете написать такой typedef:


     typedef struct TLSchema *TLSchema;


тогда надо заменить

    TLSchema schema = (TLSchema*)malloc(1000);

на

    TLSchema schema = (TLSchema)malloc(1000);

и все будет компилироваться.


--

А, собственно, возвращать из `parse_schema()` Вы хотите адрес (указатель) или структуру?

Comment: @avp внутри - белиберда. Я хочу вернуть функцией саму структуру, меня строки и возврат указателей запутали окончательно.  
Не компилируется не поэтому, а из-за объявления типа (до malloc не доходит). Я сейчас честно не могу вспомнить, какая именно проблема была, но ответ на нее нашелся на SO, и суть его свелась к объявлению значений констант внутри файла .с. Поэтому я запихнул само объявление в .с.

Простите за тупые вопросы.

Comment: @Fike, в следующий раз приводите в вопросе относящиеся к делу фрагменты кода и диагностику компилятора (точно, что он пишет).

--

А если хотите вернуть структуру, которая распределяется в функции через `mаlloc()`,  то

    typedef struct TLSchema TLSchema;
    ...
    TLSchema foo () {
       TLSchema *s = (TLSchema *)malloc(sizeof(*s));
       ...
       return *s; // возвращаем много  байтиков самой структуры, а не адрес
    }

в таком духе.

Comment: @avp, конкретно по заданному вопросу все есть в тексте наверху.

Comment: Ладно, @Fike. Меня, похоже, Вы уже окончательно запутали.

Из текста 

    typedef struct TLSchema TLSchema;
    ...
    TLSchema schema = (TLSchema*)malloc(1000);

наверху я вижу примерно такое

    ...error: invalid initializer

сообщение компилятора.